# Rebuilding Locator with ILocatorWorkspace2?

Tags: arcobjects, geocoding

Trying to use ArcObjects to rebuild locators in an IWorkspace, but enounter 'COMException was unhandled' error when trying to use the 'rebuildlocator' method on ILocatorWorkspace2.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    private static IWorkspace ws;

    IWorkspaceFactory2 wsf = new SdeWorkspaceFactoryClass();
    ws = wsf.Open(propertySet, 0);    

    private static void RebuildLocators()
    {
        System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriLocation.LocatorManager"));

        ILocatorManager locManager = (ILocatorManager)obj;
        ILocatorWorkspace2 locWs = (ILocatorWorkspace2)locManager.GetLocatorWorkspace(ws);

        IEnumLocatorName enumlocName = locWs.get_LocatorNames(esriLocatorQuery.esriLocator, "Address");
        ILocatorName locName = enumlocName.Next();
        //IEnumLocator enumloc = locWs.get_Locators(esriLocatorQuery.esriLocator, "Address");
        //ILocator loc = (ILocator)enumloc.Next();

        while (locName != null)
        {
            locWs.RebuildLocator(locName.Name, null);
            locName = (ILocatorName)enumlocName.Next();
        }
    }
```

I have tried to pass both the ILocator.Name and ILocatorName.Name, but I suspect the problem might be the ITrackCAncel.

Has anyone had success with rebuilding locators with ILocateWorkspace2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, this code does work. The problem I was having was trying to rebuild a locator which was moved from ArcSDE 9.x to our Development ArcSDE 10.x database. ArcGIS 9.x Locators must be recreated in 10

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesk...w000000.htm%20